# `cat` behaves strangely on a mounted virtio directory

Tags: linux, cat, here-document, libvirt, virtio

When I'm in a mounted directory (9p) on my gentoo-guest and do the following:

```
TMPDIR='./foo' # The directory './foo' exists and the name 'TMPDIR' is important
cat <<EOF
hello world
EOF
```

I get the following output:

```
cat: -: No such file or directory
```

As soon I unset `$TMPDIR` and/or remove `./foo` everything just works as expected.

It seems like cat depends on `$TMPDIR`. Is this a bug?

## Edit

the `strace` looks like this:

```
execve("/bin/cat", ["cat"], 0x7fffdbbfeb20 /* 23 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55eca4cce000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=22796, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 22796, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7166997000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\34\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1857312, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7166995000
mmap(NULL, 3963464, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f71663af000
mprotect(0x7f716656d000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f716676d000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1be000) = 0x7f716676d000
mmap(0x7f7166773000, 14920, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7166773000
close(3)                                = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f7166996540) = 0
mprotect(0x7f716676d000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x55eca40ce000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f716699d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f7166997000, 22796)           = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55eca4cce000
brk(0x55eca4cef000)                     = 0x55eca4cef000
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(229, 0), ...}) = 0
fstat(0, 0x7ffe16cc1ec0)                = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "cat: ", 5)                    = 5
write(2, "-", 1)                        = 1
write(2, ": No such file or directory", 27) = 27
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
close(0)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: I suspect your specific problem may be related to the fact that you are using a relative path for `$TMPDIR`. Did you try an `ls -ld $TMPDIR` before `cat`?

Comment: I've tried it with an absolute path which results the same behavior.

Comment: Did you try `strace cat <<...` to find out what's going on?

Comment: @U.Windl I did a `strace`, but I do not understand what goes wrong, it seems like somewhere the `stdin (fd=0)` goes missing

Comment: That would support my view: The problem is not `cat`, but the redirected input (which is done by the shell). The strace seems to indicate that file descriptor 0 isn't open when cat tries to read from it. Maybe then write your command in a short file (if it isn't already), then do an `strace -f -o trace_file your_shell your_script`.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by _mounted virtio_?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas 9p

Comment: Looks like this bug: [9pfs does not honor open file handles on unlinked files](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1336794)

Answer (score 0):

Actually `cat` does not depend on `$TMPDIR`, but the shell redirection `<<` does.

In this case it seems `cat` tries do do an `fstat()` on `stdin` (fd 0), and it fails for some reason (from strace):

```
fstat(0, 0x7ffe16cc1ec0)                = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

In a normal environment this is not a problem:

```
strace -f cat <<FOO
> bar
> FOO
execve("/usr/bin/cat", ["cat"], [/* 91 vars */]) = 0
```

...

```
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=4, ...}) = 0
fadvise64(0, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL) = 0
mmap(NULL, 139264, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4844156000
read(0, "bar\n", 131072)                = 4
write(1, "bar\n", 4bar
)                    = 4
read(0, "", 131072)                     = 0
munmap(0x7f4844156000, 139264)          = 0
close(0)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

So again: It's not a bug in `cat`, but some bug in the virtual environment.

Comment: but if I replace `cat` with `less` it works

Comment: Exactly, `bash` implements here-docs with temporary files. That makes them seekable.

Comment: Yes I saw that in the traces too, but why does it work on any mounted block device, but does not on a 9p-device?

Comment: the difference between `cat` and `less` is that `cat` does a `fstat()` on stdin and `less` doesn't. It's some strange hiccup or bug with virtio/9p (unfortunately, I'm not able to debug it now). But anyways, nothing to do with cat, less, bash, etc ;-)

Comment: that's most certainly caused by this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1336794), already mentioned in the [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/515421/cat-behaves-strangely-on-a-mounted-virtio-directory#comment952396_515421). I'm using nfs and cifs/samba with qemu virtual machines -- I don't know how easy is to switch to that within the constraints of the `libvirt` straight-jacket, though.